# How to get VS 2008's Add New Project dialog to show me the MVC 2 project templates?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-mvc-2

How do I get VS 2008 Professional Edition's Add New Project dialog box to show me the ASP.NET MVC 2 project type? It currently shows me only the MVC 1 project template (ASP.NET MVC Web Application).

I have both versions of MVC installed.

Comment: Did you install MVC2 before or after VS 2008?

Comment: I had VS 2008 Evaluation earlier. Then I installed VS 2010, which gave me MVC 2 out of the box. Then I upgraded by VS 2008 evaluation to a licensed version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you have VS2010 installed you still need the VS2008 project templates for MVC 2 (which installed VS2010 does do). I would download and installed MVC 2 that way you get all the project templates.